# Is there anything that will index java source, but also include information from the compiled bytecode?

Tags: java, search, solr, bcel

I need to search a large code base, and I'd like to get results to searches like:

'*Which classes call method X()*'
and
'*Give me the concrete implementers of interface Y*'

The kind of handy stuff you can do in eclipse, but which unfortunately isn't practice for me.

I was thinking of using solr and possibly adding semantic information using BCEL or similar, but it seems like this should exist already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[opengrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html). I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/ . Works with eclipse well. It might have the stuff you need.